# Antonym of "response"

Tags: antonyms

Suppose you're on an internet forum.  If post Y is a response to post X, then X is a [WHAT] to Y?  What's the antonym of "response", here?  The word coming to mind is "antecedent", but that's not the right word.  The thesauruses I looked at (online) weren't very helpful; most of them didn't list any antonyms, and the ones that did gave words only kinda relevant, in context, like "cause".

Comment: Instigator, provacateur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a *precursor* to my answer.

> precursor: one that precedes and indicates the approach of another
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/precursor)

The word offers a little extra meaning (“and indicates the approach of ...”) to that of a mere antecedent.

Answer (score 2):

By analogy with psychological and biological usage you might describe Post Y as a ***response*** to the ***stimulus*** of Post X ([*Britannica*](https://www.britannica.com/science/stimulus-response-theory))

Answer (score 1):

related, but perhaps not exactly what you want

> **call and response**
> 2. A form of verbal interaction between a speaker and listeners, usually at religious or public gatherings, in which each utterance by the speaker elicits a response from the audience.
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/call_and_response)

*example:*
Speaker: What do we want?
Crowd: Justice!
Speaker: When do we want it?
Crowd: Now!
[repeat]

Answer (score 0):

The original post in a thread is frequently referred to as the "original post" and often abbreviated as "OP."